# Python Text Editor(Very Basic)

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I'm a beginner in using Tkinter.

I'm trying to make python  text editor

This editor has options

1.new file

2.open file

3.save

4.save as

5.exit

But my 3.save option isn't working .

it's showing...Error

```
Exception in Tkinter callback

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1536, in __call__

return self.func(*args)

File "C:\Users\Shalom Alexander\Desktop\files\Sharon 's 

database\sdf_lab_by_sharon\Assignment on c and python\python assinment 

ans\mytxt2.py", line 44, in savefile

f=open(filename,'w')

TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found
```

---

## The following is my code and i'm using python 2.7.10

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog import *

filename=None

class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)

        self.master=master

    
        self.init_window()

    
    def init_window(self):

        self.master.title('Death note 2')

        self.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)

        menubar=Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu=menubar)

        File=Menu(menubar)
        File.add_command(label='New',command=self.newfile)
        File.add_command(label='Open',command=self.openfile)
        File.add_command(label='Save',command=self.savefile)
        File.add_command(label='Save as',command=self.saveasfile)
        File.add_separator()
        File.add_command(label='Exit',command=self.my_exit)
        menubar.add_cascade(label='File',menu=File)

    def newfile(self):
    
        global filename
        filename="Untitled.txt"
        text.delete(0.0,END)

    def savefile(self):
        global filename
        f=open(filename,'w')
        t=text.get(0.0,END)
        f.write(t)
        f.close()

    def saveasfile(self):

        f=asksaveasfile(mode='w')
        t=text.get(0.0,END)

        try:
            f.write(t.rstrip())
        except:
            showerror(title='Oops',message='Sorry can\'t save the file')
    def openfile(self):

        f=askopenfile(mode='r')
        t=f.read()
        text.delete(0.0,END)
        text.insert(0.0,t)

    def my_exit(self):
        exit()

root=Tk()
text=Text(root,width=500,height=500)
text.pack()
root.geometry('500x500')
My_txt_edt=Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is pretty explicit:

```
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found
```

More specifically, that "NoneType" found indicates that the open method was expecting a unicode string, but you handed it `None`.

Looks like you're hitting a code path where the global `filename` variable (terrible choice to use a global, by the way) isn't set. I'm not going to debug for you but this should give you a pointer in the right direction. It's just a bug in your code, not an issue with Tkinter or the interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

Because `filename=None` when you have click on save button (before clicking on new button).
Look this:

```
>>> open(None, 'w')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found
>>>
```

You can use this function to save:

```
def savefile(self):
    global filename

    if filename:
        f=open(filename,'w')
        t=text.get(0.0,END)
        f.write(t)
        f.close()
    else:
        f=asksaveasfile(mode='w',defaultextension=".txt")
        if f:
            text2save=text.get(0.0,END)
            f.write(text2save)
            f.close()
```

If you want to set default `filename` after saving, replace save function with:

```
def write(self, filename, text):
    f=open(filename,'w')
    f.write(text)
    f.close()

def savefile(self):
    global filename

    txt = text.get(0.0,END)
    if filename:
        self.write(filename, txt)
    else:
        ask=asksaveasfilename()
        if ask:
            filename = ask
            self.write(filename, txt)
```